Do I need model calibration/feature normalization for reliable path integrated gradient/sampled Shapley feature attribution in a dnn model?
Are model calibration and feature normalization required for path integrated gradient and sampled Shapley-based feature attribution analyses to work properly in a deep neural network model?
I read that while not strictly mandatory, model calibration and feature normalization substantially improve the reliability and interpretability of these attribution methods. Without them, inherent model biases due to poor scaling or probability distribution may be reflected in the attributions.
However, I think that this doesn't mean PIG or Sampled Shapley worsen the problem, but rather that they will faithfully represent the model's decision-making process, even if that process is flawed due to lack of calibration or normalization.
If my goal is to understand how an unreliable model weighs its features, can't I use PIG or Sampled Shapley and accept their results as ground truth for how that specific model functions?
Please let me know if there's something I'm missing.
